# What are the invariant factors of a matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I understand what the invariant factors of a finitely generated module over an ED are, but what does it mean to ask, say, for the invariant factors of a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$?

I cannot find a clear source for this online. Apparently they are the invariant factors in the smith normal form of $M-xI$ in $R[X]$ but I don’t see how they relate to invariant factors of a module.

Comment: The invariant factors are $1$ because every nonzero element is a unit over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're looking for the similarity invariants, which are the invariant factors of the characteristic matrix.

Comment: @daruma my thoughts exactly

Comment: @blargoner So if I wanted to put a matrix into rational canonical form, why do I want the invariant factors of the characteristic matrix (I know the full proof of RCF, but I can’t join the dots here)?

Comment: @Morg It's hard to tell what type of answer would satisfy you. I mean you can see from a proof using SNF that the matrix and the direct sum of the companion matrices of its similarity invariants have the same similarity invariants, so are similar. (Assuming you mean weak form of RCF, some authors use the term for the version w/ elementary divisors.) But maybe your question is why, intuitively, does the characteristic matrix capture this info.